# Exception has occured. Segmentation Fault

Tags: arrays, c

I am getting this segmentation error and I can seem to find where it is occuring. I am trying to create a list of float values through an array of floats. It is one of my assignment from college class.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YYSJ.png)

I have tried to comment out the float array all together to see if that is where the error is occuring but it seems the error always happens after scanf and it asks for a user size of the array.

Comment: Put source code into questions as text, not images.

Comment: `scanf("%d" ,size);` is wrong. Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`. Pay attention to the compiler messages.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &numList[i]);` Is wrong too. You get to use a pointer, this time, but the format specifier should be `%f` (same for `printf`). Also, *always* check the value returned by `scanf` (possibly avoid it altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code segfaults because `scanf()` expects a [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to store the data that was read.

In your case `scanf("%d", size);` with `size` initialized to `0` (see `size = 0`) means `scanf` should store the data at address `0` which is an invalid pointer to write and read from ([NULL pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer)).

However, it doesn't really matter that you're trying to write to a NULL pointer, any other fixed pointer would most likely cause a segfault too (i.e. if `size` were `2` or `242353252` it would *still* segfault). Segfault simply means your program accessed an *invalid* memory location ; and there are A LOT of invalid memory locations that could be accessed by your program.

That's why your program segfaults.

To get the address of a variable use the `&` operator:

```c
scanf("%d", &size);
```

Now `scanf` receives the address of whatever address `size` is stored at.

---

```
scanf("%d", &numList[i]);
```

Is also wrong, but for a different reason: `%d` expects an `int` variable, but you're passing the address of a `float` variable.

Comment: Surprising fact of the day: If `size` is zero and is converted to a pointer, that might not be a null pointer, even if `NULL` is defined to be `0` or `(void *) 0`.